# Как отключить include?

Tags: php

Есть код и в нем подинклюдены другие файлы, шаблоны. В определенной части кода, в условии, мне нужно отключить этот самый инклюд и возможно ли это сделать? Есть выход созданием нового файла, но хотелось бы, чтобы все было в одном файле.

Comment: что за бредовый вопрос?

Если инклуды написаны в условии, значит и файлы подключаются по условию.

Это кому-то было нужно!?

отключить инклуд можно не вызывая сам инклуд.

Comment: Инклюды подключены вне условий

Comment: Так подключите их в условиях и нет проблемы.   

    if ($all_okey) include("my.inc"):

Comment: Условий много, иначе так бы и сделал.

Comment: Выгрузить инклуд Вы уже не сможете, в определенном месте, где у Вас возникли условия для неподключения задайте глобальный флаг, а в месте инклуда проверяйте этот флаг.

Comment: можно и так попробовать, спасибо...

Comment: >Инклюды подключены вне условий

Если так подключены то хрен отключишь.

Делай свои условия и подключай как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Если `include` используется то она просто загружается вставляется в код вместо себя например:

Файл `p1.php`:

```
$df="fef";
function somefunc(){...}
```

Главный файл:

```
include p1.php;
$s=5;
```

тогда исполняемый результат будет таким:

```
$df="fef";
function somefunc(){...}
$s=5;
```

а соответственно нечего нельзя откатить зато можно заменить:

Файл `p1.php`:

```
$df="fef";
function somefunc(){//определение1...}
```

Главный файл:

```
include p1.php;    
$df=NULL;
function somefunc(){return NULL;}
```

тогда исполняемый результат будет таким:

```
$df="fef";
function somefunc(){...}
$df=NULL;
function somefunc(){return NULL;}
```

Тогда результат подключения файла можно как бы "перекрыть".
К тому же лучше использовать `require`  вместо `include` т.к. первая не возвращяет ошибок если не сможет подключить файл.А ещё лучше использовать `require_once` т.к. после "перекрытия" вашим кодом другие строки подключения того же файла не перекроют  снова ваши строки